# VLC can't play large raw avi 1080p video

Tags: video, vlc, playback, realtime, avi

I recorded a huge raw avi video using SimpleScreenRecorder but it can't be played smoothly.

Every about 10 seconds the video stops to render.

How can I avoid this. I don't think my computer can't render it. I think it just needs some configuration. I need to know how to debug to find out where the problem is and "do an override" if necessary to get it to play. Or at least make sure that my computer really can't render it.

Comment: How did you produce that video? I guess it wasn't a live recording since you wouldn't have been able to record it fast enough to that drive. May there's a way to compress the video on the fly while (re-)producing. If you want to avoid lossy compression use the lossless mode of H.264.

Comment: @DavidFoerster well actually it was a live recording XD It's taken with "SSR" (in the repos). It's about 65GB for about 6 minutes (It's not natural I know). When I was recording it my computer was slowly dying. Some resource was slowly being consumed (not sure what, probably RAM). I was lucky to kill SSR just before the computer would freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check your systems manager what you CPU load is? How big and long is your file. RAW Videos can quite big and take some time to load from harddisks. Maybe there your problem comes from.

With iostat you can check your io's to your harddisk (if you think it could be the problem) 
[Here](http://www.pythian.com/blog/basic-io-monitoring-on-linux/) you can finde a description how to use it.

Comment: okay I used `dstat` and yes apparently the hard disk doesn't read fast enough. it shows that it reads at 150M while the video's running. I think that's the maximum read speed of my HDD. I also monitored cpu & gpu usage and neither of them feels load