# Hard disk's too slow to play a huge raw AVI file

Tags: video, vlc, playback, realtime, avi

I have a huge AVI file. The video player (VLC) stops every about 10 seconds because the HDD doesn't read fast enough. [(details here)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715787/vlc-cant-play-large-raw-avi-1080p-video)

I want to be able to play this video. Anyone knows a workaround?

Is it possible to load up a larger part of the video in the RAM maybe? Is there a way to do that in VLC? Or another Video player that can do that?

**edit:**
here's part of the output of running vlc with the -vvv parameter. I captured the part when the playback stopped. The output covers two stops.

```
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: resuming after 68308432 us
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: suspended
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: started
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: changing sink 2: alsa_output.usb-0d8c_USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00-Device.iec958-stereo (CM108 Audio Controller Digital Stereo (IEC958))
[0x7fa92c001248] main vout display debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
[0x19159f8] main audio output debug: resampling stopped (drift: -786 us)
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 56 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 39 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 22 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 6 ms)
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 361 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder warning: early picture skipped
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] rawvideo decoder warning: invalid frame size (128 < 3110400)
[0x7fa938da48b8] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: End of video preroll
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: Received first picture
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 6%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 13%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 20%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 27%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 34%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 41%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 48%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 55%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 62%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 69%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 76%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 82%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 89%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 96%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Stream buffering done (375 ms in 471 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 49 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 33 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 16 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 3 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 362 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder warning: early picture skipped
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] rawvideo decoder warning: invalid frame size (128 < 3110400)
[0x7fa938da48b8] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: End of video preroll
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: Received first picture
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 6%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 13%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 20%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 27%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 34%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 41%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 48%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 55%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 62%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 68%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 75%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 82%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 89%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 96%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Stream buffering done (375 ms in 436 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-390096): playing silence
[0x19159f8] main audio output debug: inserting 17203 zeroes
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 21 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 4 ms)
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 56 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 39 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 23 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 6 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 363 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder warning: early picture skipped
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] rawvideo decoder warning: invalid frame size (128 < 3110400)
[0x7fa938da48b8] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: End of video preroll
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: Received first picture
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 6%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 13%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 20%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 27%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 34%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 41%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 48%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 55%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 61%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 68%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 75%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 82%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 89%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 96%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Stream buffering done (375 ms in 486 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 56 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 39 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 23 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 6 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 65 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 49 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 32 ms)
[0x7fa980c56038] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 15 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 364 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] rawvideo decoder warning: invalid frame size (128 < 3110400)
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa938da48b8] main decoder debug: End of audio preroll
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: End of video preroll
[0x7fa938c0bfe8] main decoder debug: Received first picture
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: underflow
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 6%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 13%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 20%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 27%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 34%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 41%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 48%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 54%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 61%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 68%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 75%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 82%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 89%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Buffering 96%
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Stream buffering done (375 ms in 440 ms)
[0x7fa9400009b8] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: changing sink 2: alsa_output.usb-0d8c_USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00-Device.iec958-stereo (CM108 Audio Controller Digital Stereo (IEC958))
[0x7fa92c001248] main vout display debug: auto hiding mouse cursor
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: suspended
[0x19159f8] pulse audio output debug: changing sink 2: alsa_output.usb-0d8c_USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00-Device.iec958-stereo (CM108 Audio Controller Digital Stereo (IEC958))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm not able to comment yet. Can you run VLC with `-vvv` option:

```
vlc -vvv video.avi
```

and provide some output so we can better understand what is happening there. Thanks.

**Edit:**
You also could try to increase Caching value in VLCs settings. Go to `Media -> Open Multiple Files` then go to File tab and set the checkbox `Show more options`:

[image]

Comment: there's the output. I also tried adjusting the cache and it seemed to work at first but sadly I can't adjust it. I first tried 3000ms, it played the first 40 seconds perfectly but then did buffering. ...When I tried to increase the caching even more it made weird glitches from the beginning

Comment: @MinaMichael there are also many audio underflow messages. Can you try to demultiplex only video to make sure that this is not a synchronisation issue?

Comment: okay, how do I do that? XD

Comment: go to `Audio -> Audio Track -> Disable` while playing the video.

Comment: okay I disabled the audio and tried playing, it's not fixed

Comment: hmm. So this is not a sync issue then. Did you also try another players e.g. ffplay, mplayer, MP4Client (from GPAC, my favorite) etc. Is it always the same? If yes, maybe using different video card drivers will help.

Comment: I just tried xine, banshee, parole and ubuntu's default video player "videos"  ..non of them could play it LOL XD

Comment: haha. I'm so sorry )) But give this MP4Client a try. It helped me a lot